# Django sometimes gives 404 and sometimes gives 200

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

With the same configuration in Django, visiting the same URL

```
http://<URL>/basic/insert/adafd
```

sometimes gives me a 404 while it will give me a 200 later. Any idea how would this happen and how to solve it?

(Looks like it occurs after I tried to use channels)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^insert/(.*)$', views.insert),
    url(r'^list$', views.list),
]
```

Other code cut down as follows:

```
def listfrom(request, last):
    stack = infoStack.objects.all()
    listing = []
    for info in stack:
        if info.id()>last:
            listing.append(info.as_dict())
            request.session['last'] = info.id() 
    return render(request, "basic/list.html", {"listings": json.dumps(listing)})

def list(request):  
    last = 0
    if request.session.keys():
        sid = request.session.session_key
        s = Session.objects.get(pk=sid)     
        last = s.get_decoded()['last']
    return listfrom(request, last)

def insert(request, info):
    ip = get_client_ip(request)
    q = infoStack()
    q.infoIP = ip
    q.infoText = info
    q.save()
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.status_code = 200
    return response
```

Channel related config/code as follows:

```
@channel_session    
def ws_message(message):
    print "message"     

@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    print "connect"
    Group("wsg").add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})        

@channel_session
def ws_disconnect(message):
    print "disconnect"
    Group("wsg").discard(message.reply_channel)


# routing.py
from basic.views import ws_message, ws_connect, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = {
    'websocket.connect': ws_connect,
    'websocket.receive': ws_message,
    'websocket.disconnect': ws_disconnect,
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: looks like you don't have it set up to handle when a session keys don't exist

Comment: would that be the cause? since it also occurs when I refresh the page. where I suppose the cookie is already there.

Comment: What is the url you try to reach?

Comment: http://<URL>/basic/insert/adafd

Comment: could you post the views related to the url in question?

Comment: In your insert view try to wrap save statement with try catch and check if dont causing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found a post about this, https://github.com/django/channels/issues/489

Basically, the issue gone after I have uninstalled the redis-server and install it again.